# How to remove all symbols within a given string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, replaceall

Currently I am using the following Javascript code to convert a product title into URL-slug within the base template of my django project.

```
document.getElementById("title").onkeyup = function () {
    document.getElementById("url_slug").value = document
      .getElementById("title")
      .value.toLowerCase()
      .replaceAll(" ", "-")
      .replaceAll("'", "")
  };
```

This is using consecutive replaceAll() methods to replace space with dash then remove apostrophes but i would like to prevent all other symbols (e.g. +=()[]$%@#... etc) as well.

Surely there must be a better way?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: This is not how Django itself constructs slugs: it will for example first aim to strip diacritics from characters, such that `ü` is for example mapped on `u`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all characters with regex expression   /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g

```
document.getElementById("title").onkeyup = function () {
    document.getElementById("url_slug").value = document
      .getElementById("title")
      .value.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g,'')
      .replaceAll(" ", "-")
      .replaceAll("'", "")
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
let stringToReplace = '12+3%42()S$%\|#s'
let desired = stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
```

The  (**^**) character is the negation of whatever comes in the set [...],

**gi** stands for: global and case-insensitive

Plus we put a **safelist** in there:

In our case digits, chars, underscores (\w) whitespace (\s).

So whatever is out of our whitelist gots replaced with ''